# How to change the ant directory to excute ant task from different folder

Tags: ant

There are two build files placed in different folder

`folder1/build.xml`

`folder1/subfolder/sub/build.xml`

I am having exectable task in `folder1/build.xml`

```
<exec dir="." executable="${tools.versionupdater.exe}" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="${dist.path}" />
  <arg value="${build.version}" />
  <arg value="${build.version}" />
</exec>
```

which is running properly because which can find `visionupdater.exe` that is placed in `folder1/tools/VersionUpdater/versionupdater.exe` under same root folder.

How can I run the `versionupdater.exe` from another build file 
which is placed in `folder1/subfolder/sub/build.xml`?

Comment: What is the value of `${tools.versionupdater.exe}`? Also, is folder1/subfolder/sub/build.xml launched from folder1/build.xml? Or is folder1/subfolder/sub/build.xml launched by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can really only happen if `${tools.versionupdater.exe}` expands to a relative path that is resolvable from `folder1` but isn't resolvable from `folder1/subfolder/sub`.

The way to work around it depends on how exactly are you making the call to `exec`.

1. If both `folder1/build.xml` and `folder1/subfolder/sub/build.xml` contain the same `exec` task (duplicated), then the only way you can make this work is to ensure that the value of the `tools.versionupdater.exe` property is an *absolute*, rather than a *relative*, path.
2. If `folder1/subfolder/sub/build.xml` calls a target in `folder1/build.xml`, then ensure that you're using the `ant` task instead of `antcall`, providing the `dir` attribute:

   ```
   <ant antfile="../../build.xml" dir="../../" target="...">
       ... parameters ...
   </ant>
   ```